# Choosing a suitable learning rate based on validation or testing accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I have simulated a neural network with different learning rate, ranging from 0.00001 to 0.1, and recording each test and validation accuracy. The result i obtained is as below. There is 50 epoch for each learning rate, and i note down the validation accuracy at the last epoch, while the training accuracy is computed throughout the process.

Learning rate: **0.00001**

Testing accuracy: 0.5850

Validation accuracy at final epoch: 0.5950

---

Learning rate: **0.0001**

Testing accuracy:0.6550

Validation accuracy at final epoch: 0.6400

---

Learning rate: **0.001**

Testing accuracy: 0.6350

Validation accuracy at final epoch: 0.6900

---

Learning rate: **0.01**

Testing accuracy: 0.6650

Validation accuracy at final epoch: 0.6700

---

Learning rate: **0.1**

Testing accuracy: 0.2500

Validation accuracy at final epoch: 0.2100

How does testing and validation accuracy influence which learning rate is better? Would a higher validation accuracy determine the **most suitable learning rate** for the model?

Hence, is it correct that 0.001 is the most suitable learning parameter since it has the highest validation accuracy at the last epoch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot select a parameter based on test accuracy, because the moment you do that, it becomes a validation accuracy as it has **affected** the final model. Therefore, you are always choosing based on validation accuracy.

As a result, the best result comes from learning rate 0.001, with the highest validation accuracy 0.6900. We have ignored `Testing accuracy`. If we select based on `Testing accuracy`, it becomes a validation accuracy.

Generally, a learning rate that is a looser at epoch 50, might be a winner at epoch 200. In other words, a slower convergence may lead to a higher accuracy. Therefore, this issue is worth considering too.

Comment: Further to this, consider a learning rate schedule - it's often the case that reducing or cycling the learning rate on a schedule can lead to better results that simply using a single value.